# Write a SQL query to get the version lower then the Authorize version

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table name XYZ having col. names:-

```
id(varchar),
Version(Number),
Authorize_state(Y/N),
Action(Save/Reset/Delete/... etc)
```

I have to get all the versions for Authorize_state='N' lower then the versions for which Authorize_state='Y' 
e.g.

```
Table
ID.   Version.     Authorize_state     Action
1A.     2.                 N.                      Save
1A.     3.                 N.                      Save
1A.     5.                 Y.                      Update
1A.     8.                 N.                      Reset
1B.     1.                 N.                       DO
1B.     3.                 Y.                      Accept
1B.     5.                 N.                      Save
```

1 - So now i have to get 1st version of Id 1B and 2 and 3 version of Id 1A 
2 - Y version  for a perticular id will always be one in the table.

Please help me to write a sql query for the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  id,
  min(version) min_v
from xyz
where Authorize_state='Y'
group by id
```

To get minimal authorize version for each id

```
select
  xyz.*
from xyz
  inner join (the query above) sub on xyz.id = sub.id and xyz.version<sub.version
```

then join original table with minimal leaving only versions lower than found mins